# java.io.IOException: http1_0 content, bytes received: 112

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I get this error when executing the following Code:

```
public static String MakeRequest2(RequestItem requestItem, String pattern) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        var client = HttpClient
                .newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .build();
        
        
        var request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .uri(URI.create(Finals.ServerPath))
                .GET()
                .header("SenderContent", "Test")
                //.header("Content-Type", "text/html")
                //.expectContinue(false)
                .build();
        
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        
        return "";
    }
```

And he should recieve

```
public final String wrongFormatHttpAnswer = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n" +
            "Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT\n" +
            "Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)\n" +
            "Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT\n" +
            "Content-Type: text/html\n" +
            "Response: NoMessageDelivered\n" +
            "Connection: Closed\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
            "<title>\n" +
            "Wrong server\n" +
            "</title>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "<h1>Hey buddy, you are on the wrong Server :)</h1>\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";
```

But the server does not receive anything and the program crashes with the at the top stated exception.

I don't get it, where the http1_0 content comes from.

I hope you guys can help me.